# getNextSibling() method does not return any results

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

I am writing a code to read XML files and labeling the nodes. I am using the DOM Java.  The method getNextSibling() is not returning any results as the other methods like getParentNode do.  What could be the problem?

Comment: can I see your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Node getNextSibling()
```

**The node immediately following this node. If there is no such node, this returns null.** This from the documentation.

By the way, this question has already been examined in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641496/how-can-i-get-the-siblings-of-an-xml-element-in-java-using-the-dom-parser).